# Can a rogue take the feat Extra Rogue Talent at level 1?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, rogue

Can a rogue take the feat Extra Rogue Talent at level 1?

They don't receive a rogue talent until level 2, but is that still considered a class feature?

Comment: I notice that the [extra rogue talent feat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/extra-rogue-talent) has "rogue talent class feature" for a prerequisite, but one could interpret that the rogue has that class feature even at level 1, I suppose.

Comment: @doppelgreener that's pretty much what I'm asking 

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just to include the official Paizo response on this topic so that there is no doubt:

The prerequisite for taking the Extra Rogue Talent feat is "rogue talent class feature". According to the [official Pathfinder FAQ](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9qt8), you don't have a class feature until you reach the appropriate level in the class.

From the link above:

> You have a class feature when your class description tells you you gain that class feature, generally based on your level in that class (and perhaps altered by factors, see below).

So no, you wouldn't be able to take Extra Rogue Talent until 2nd level.

Comment: I'm going to make this the answer because of the link to the official FAQ

Answer (score 10):

At first level, a rogue has a level in a class which grants the Rogue Talent class feature, but does not yet have that feature (just like they don't have the Evasion class feature). A rogue would have to wait 'til they actually attain their second rogue level to take that particular feat.

As a GM, I would be inclined to allow a character to take the feat early, though.

Comment: I appreciate the insight on taking the feat early